# Deciphering the main theorem of the paper ''On Oblath's Problem''

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, integers

I am trying to read the paper [On Oblath's Problem](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Panaitopol/panaitopol41.pdf), and I'm have difficulty understanding the main theorem. I can read the theorem but I don't understand it. May someone help me to make this theorem as simple as it can be? Can you help to elaborate this theorem in the simplest way so that I can understand?

> Theorem: The squares whose decimal representation makes use of $k \geqslant 2$ digits, such that $k − 1$ of these digits are equal, are precisely $$16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 121, 144, 225, 441,
> 484, 676, 1444, 44944, 10^{2i}
> , 4 · 10^{2i} \text{ and } 9 · 10^{2i}$$
>   with $i \geqslant 1$.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what is or isn't making sense to you?  Do you, for instance, understand the statement of the theorem (which you have quoted)?  Do you understand the argument for the solution for $\geq 5$-digit squares?  Et c...

Comment: i dont understand what dos it imply.What the theoem really wants to find out.For example ,the Pythagorean theorem, it is a theorem that can be used in finding the angles of right triange, that is what i am looking for this theorem.I dont know what is the purpose of such theorem ,what it is finding and what does the theorem (as a whole) mean.

Comment: The squares whose decimal representation makes use of k⩾2 digits, such that k−1 of these digits are equal,                            im a little bit confused in this part also, what do you mean by  k is greater than or equal to 2 digits? does that mean that digits that a specific number consists,like 25,so it has 2 digits-2 and 5? then k-1 so 2-1 then 1 as a difference? thn what is the relation of that to  16,25,36,49,64,81,121,144,225,441,484,676,1444,44944,102i,4⋅102i and 9⋅102i

Comment: the title of my rsearch is actually "Perfect Powers With All Equal Digits But
One" but i thought tht i really need to understand the oblath's problem so that i can understand my topic as well,but sadly, i cant understand yet oblath's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first paragraph of the paper you link describes Oblath's problem:  find all perfect powers $n^m$ whose decimal representation consist of repetitions of the same digit.  The paper then poses the question: find all squares having all equal digits but one (intentionally phrased by me using the language from the title of your research).

Unpacking your linked paper's Theorem 1.1 in excruciating detail:  Let $n$ be a (positive) integer.  Let $k$ be the length of the number $n^2$ expressed in decimal.  Restrict interest to $n$ such that $k \geq 2$ (that is, we are only interested in squares whose decimal representation has length at least two).  Restrict interest to the $n$ such that $k-1$ of the digits in the decimal representation of $n^2$ are the same (that is, we are only interested in squares that have all equal digits but one).  Then the only values of $n^2$ that are left after the two restrictions are $16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 121, 144, 225, 441, 484, 676, 1444, 44944$, and the three infinite families $100$, $10\,000$, $1\,000\,000$, $\dots, 10^{2i}$; $400$, $40\,000$, $4\,000\,000$, $\dots, 4 \cdot 10^{2i}$; and $900$, $90\,000$, $9\,000\,000$, $\dots, 9 \cdot 10^{2i}$, for $i \geq 1$ (that is, the infinite families are generated by the indicated general term by letting $i$ range over all positive integers that are greater than or equal to $1$).

This seems to resolve your research for all squares, but does not resolve your research for higher (prime) powers.  You may get insight into your research for higher powers from Oblath's paper directly.  (I wouldn't know; I haven't read it.)

EDIT 20160625:  There's an alternative viewpoint.  Pick two digits, $a$ and $b$ and a positive integer, $k$, with $k \geq 2$.  Now construct all permutations of $1$ "$a$" and $k-1$ "$b$"s.  For instance, with $a=9, b=4, k=5$, these are "$94444$", "$49444$", "$44944$", "$44494$", and "$44449$".  For each of these that is a square (only $44944$), its square root is an $n$ of interest ($n = 212$).  For $a=3, b=6, k=2$, these are "$36$" and "$63$", only $36$ is a square, and $n=6$ is an $n$ of interest.  Note that when $k=2$, $a$ and $b$ are interchangeable -- both $a=3, b=6, k=2$ and $a=6, b=3, k=2$ give the same set of permutations, so we may consider either digit to be the one repeated $k-1$ times.

For most choices of $(a,b,k)$, none of the permutations is a square, so most choices of $(a,b,k)$ give no $n$ of interest.  The theorem states that the only choices that are interesting are:

```
(a,b,k):  n^2
(1,6,2), (6,1,2): 16
(2,5,2), (5,2,2): 25
(3,6,2), (6,3,2): 36
(4,9,2), (9,4,2): 49
(4,6,2), (6,4,2): 64
(1,8,2), (8,1,2): 81
(2,1,3): 121  (Note: (1,2,3) gives 122, 212, 221, none of which are square)
(1,4,3): 144
(5,2,3): 225
(1,4,3): 441
(8,4,3): 484
(7,6,3): 676
(1,4,4): 1444
(9,4,5): 44944
(1,0,2i): 10^(2i)
(4,0,2i): 4 * 10^(2i)
(9,0,2i): 9 * 10^(2i)
```

The examples with repeated zeroes suggest we should add a rule: "$0$" is never the first digit of a square of interest, otherwise, we would have to consider "$00100$" as a square with $(a,b,k) = (1,0,4)$, which would be silly since this square is found with $(1,0,2)$.

Comment: thank you so much Eric , you do not know how you save my life.Thanks

Comment: it seems simpler now and understandable.thank you sooooooooooooo much

Comment: hi eric, i can understand the theorem already but not totally, im still confused about some matters, can i ask the meaning of it when we say that "squares that have all equal digits but one" im confused in that especially in that part "but one".May i ask some examples of it.please

Comment: sorry ,because english is not my mother-tongue ,and it takes me a lot of time to understand "squares that have all equal digits but one" this is my interpretation and please corrct me if my wrong.

Comment: the square of the numbers which have the same numbers which are equal but there is this only number which is not the same with the others, like  44944 is a perfect square and it has the same numbers ( the four 4) and there is a digit which is the only one which is not the same with the others,(that is 9) . Is my interpretation correct? then what about  16, 25, 36, 64? (what do you mean by squares that have all equal digits but one when we refer to these numbers?

Comment: @user350030 e.g. $16$ has $k=2$, and  $16$ has $k-1=1$ digits the same and 1 digit different, so it 'obviously' works. That's why all the 2 digit squares are there.

Comment: 16 has 2 digits , 1 and 6 and they are different with each other,but where can we compare that           "one digit" so that we can say that they are the same?please help me understand it..

Comment: @user350030 : "16" has two digits, "1" and "6".  All the digits are the same ("1") except for one, which is "6".  Alternatively, all the digits are "6" except for one, which is "1".  When the length, $k$, is two, we are free to pick either digit as "the repeated one" and the other digit as "the exception" -- it's just that the repeated one only occurs once.

Comment: @user350030 : I've added a bit to my Answer about the other viewpoint to take on this question.